# How To ' Write To New .CSV File' or "Save As New .CSV File' In python

Tags: python, csv, one-hot-encoding

I have a CSV file, I want to apply One hot encoding, then save the new dataframe(dataset) as a new CSV file. But when the new file is saved, it only writes 5 Rows of dummies and all rows of original dataset!

I just want to save all rows and columns in the new file.csv, the final shape of the dataset is `(237124, 417)`.

my code contain:

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder 
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder 
import csv

dataset=pd.read_csv("C:/Users/User/Desktop/data.csv",encoding='cp1252')
dataset.shape
#output: (237124, 37)

dummies = pd.get_dummies(dataset, columns=["name","mark",....... ]).head()
dummies.shape
#output : (5, 380)

dataset = pd.concat([dataset, dummies], axis=1)
dataset.shape
#output: (237124, 417)
# i want this shape(original+dummies)

dataset.to_csv('OneHotEncodnig.csv', index=False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call `df.head()` in this line:

```py
dummies = pd.get_dummies(dataset, columns=["name","mark",....... ]).head()
```

This is why you only get 5 dummy rows. Remove the `.head()` and you get all rows.

Answer (score 1):

`head()` function will return only 5 rows by default. Please apply `get_dummies()` without `head()` function

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder 
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder 
import csv

dataset=pd.read_csv("C:/Users/User/Desktop/data.csv",encoding='cp1252')
dataset.shape
#output: (237124, 37)

dummies = pd.get_dummies(dataset, columns=["name","mark",....... ])
dummies.shape
#output : (5, 380)

dataset = pd.concat([dataset, dummies], axis=1)
dataset.shape
#output: (237124, 417)
# i want this shape(original+dummies)

dataset.to_csv('OneHotEncodnig.csv', index=False)
```